# Python matplotlib wrong pick events on artists after zoom

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib and basemap embedded in a PyQt5 dialog.I have a group of artists that i want to do a functionality.Most of the time all works fine but sometimes when i click out of artists region or in some other artist wrong artist triggers ,and the weirdest of all is that this happens for multiple(wrong) artists at once.

It's seems to be that after zoom artists keeps its previous position

Mimum example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
from matplotlib.patches import Circle,Rectangle,PathPatch,Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np
import random



def on_pick(event):
    if event.mouseevent.button == 1 and isinstance(event.artist, AnnotationBbox) == True and event.artist.get_gid() != None:
        artist = event.artist
        pid = artist.get_gid()
        print(pid)
        return True



figure,ax = plt.subplots(1)#,num="Map viewer")
def format_coord(x, y):
    try:
        x,y = m(x, y,inverse = True)
        if y<-90 or y>90 or x<-180 or x>180:
            pass
        else:
            if y < 0:
                S_OR_N = "S"
                y = abs(y)
                int_part = int(y)
                min_part = int((y - int_part)*60)

                seconds_part = int(( y - int_part - (min_part/60))*3600)
            elif y > 0:
                S_OR_N = "N"
                y = abs(y)
                int_part = int(y)
                min_part = int((y - int_part)*60)
                seconds_part = int(( y - int_part - (min_part/60))*3600)
            else:
                S_OR_N = ""

            if x < 0:
                E_OR_W = "W"
                x = abs(x)
                int_part2 = int(x)
                min_part2 = int((x - int_part2)*60)

                seconds_part2 = int(( x - int_part2 - (min_part2/60))*3600)
            elif x > 0:
                E_OR_W = "E"
                x = abs(x)
                int_part2 = int(x)
                min_part2 = int((x - int_part2)*60)        
                seconds_part2 = int(( x - int_part2 - (min_part2/60))*3600)
            else:
                E_OR_W = ""
            return '{} {}° {}\' {}\"   {} {}° {}\' {}"'.format(E_OR_W,str(int_part2).zfill(3),str(min_part2).zfill(2),str(seconds_part2).zfill(2),
                                                                  S_OR_N,str(int_part).zfill(2),str(min_part).zfill(2),str(seconds_part).zfill(2))
    except:
        pass


ax.format_coord = format_coord 
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,\
        llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,lat_ts=20,resolution='c')
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,30))
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,10)) 
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
# fill continents, set lake color same as ocean color.
m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')

#### rundom coordinates ####
list_random = []
for i in range (0,400):
    x = random.randrange(-180, 180)
    y = random.randrange(-90, 90)
    list_random.append([x,y])

id = 0 
airport = np.array(Image.open('test_alt.png'))###3 change here for any small(50x50) image
for i in list_random:
    im = OffsetImage(airport,zoom = 0.22)
    ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (float(i[0]),float(i[1])), xycoords='data',frameon=False)
    ab.set_gid(id)
    ab.set_picker(0.1)
    ax.add_artist(ab)
    id+=1

pick = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event',on_pick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve], i.e. a minimal runnable code that shows the issue.

Comment: y sorry i prepare minimum

Comment: still same out put with this example

Comment: its something with zoom im trying to see the workaround as this problem occurs only when map zoomed